# Add links in PDF

Tags: windows, pdf, hyperlink

I have a PDF that has many notes of the form `§6 a` which mean to go to section 6, note a (already a bookmarked location).

Similarly, I have many notes that are of the form `Bb cc:vv` which refer to verses in the bible.

I am comfortable writing a regex that can break these pattern into their constituent parts, and transforming them into the the needed destinations, (e.g. Bb cc:vv => example.com/bb/cc+vv), but is there a way to make both of these things into real links?

I should note that the identification of these locations is easy (they are a different color in the text, and are easy to match.

I am looking for something that can deal with a PDF file, can be either free or paid, and run on Windows.

If it helps, I already have Adobe Acrobat XI.

Comment: How was the pdf created? It might be easier from there if you have access.

Comment: @Bernhard I have no idea. Its just an old out of print book I found on archive.org