# Adding internal links in a pdf document using free program in ubuntu

Tags: linux, pdf, ubuntu, pdf-editor

I am trying to add a table of contents to a collection of pdfs I have joined to a single pdf to submit for an application. (I used [pdf arranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger) for this)

I have added a first page with the contents, however I would like to add internal links to the pages of each document. My question is similar to [Add links in PDF](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/add-links-in-pdf) which unfortunately has no answers. However, I do not have acrobat and would preferably like to use a free, available for linux solution for the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepare a suitable `bookmarks.txt` or `bookmarks.json` file, and then use `cpdf -set-bookmarks bookmarks.txt in.pdf -o out.pdf` or `cpdf -set-bookmarks-json bookmarks.json in.pdf -o out.pdf` as appropriate. A `bookmarks.txt` file might look like this:

```
0 "Part 1" 1 open
1 "Part 1A" 2
1 "Part 1B" 3
0 "Part 2" 4
1 "Part 2a" 5
```

The format details are in the manual, linked from https://community.coherentpdf.com/

Answer (score 2):

Ended up using latex to create the table of contents... @johnwhitington's solution looks simpler, so I set this as the answer, but I was pretty happy with the pdf i created... Here is a simplification of the latex code used...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\sectionfont{\centering}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\section*{Documents Index:}

\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{c p{38em}}
        \hyperref[anx:1]{Annex 1:}& \hyperref[anx:1]{This is a title} \\
        \hyperref[anx:2]{Annex 2:}& \hyperref[anx:2]{And another }\\
        \hyperref[anx:3]{Annex 3:}& \hyperref[anx:3]{And so on... }\\
......
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\newpage

{\phantomsection}\label{anx:1}
\includepdf[pages=1]{ev.pdf}
{\phantomsection}\label{anx:2}
\includepdf[pages=2]{ev.pdf}
{\phantomsection}\label{anx:3}
\includepdf[pages=3]{ev.pdf}
.........
\includepdf[pages=11-]{ev.pdf}

\end{document}
```